# Django how to remove a user from a group

Tags: django, usergroups

Here is the code I add a user to a group

```
g = Group.objects.get(name='groupname') 
g.user_set.add(your_user)
```

When I delete a User how I remove this user from group?

Comment: If you delete a user, you shouldn't need to remove it from the group.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/#methods

```
g.user_set.remove(your_user)
```

Answer (score 18):

The simplest method to clear all user groups from the user object is

```
user_obj.groups.clear()
```

Answer (score 16):

To remove a specific Group:

```py
group = Group.objects.get(name='groupname') 
user.groups.remove(group)
```